# Create object using unique_ptr

Tags: c++

I have `enum class` with 3 types of objects. Need to create an appropriate type of object using `unique_ptr`. But compiler throws lots of errors. One them: `invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'ObjectManager'
     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }`

Maybe I am using wrong creation method?

Here is my code:

### ObjectManager.h

```
class ObjectManager
{
public:
    virtual void play(const std::string &sound) const = 0;
    virtual void pause() const = 0;
    virtual void stop() const = 0;
    virtual void resume() const = 0;
};
```

---

### ObjectType.h

```
enum class ObjectType
{
    type1,
    type2,
    type3
};
```

---

### ObjectFactory.h

```
class ObjectFactory
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    static unique_ptr<ObjectManager> create(ObjectType type);
};
```

---

### ObjectFactory.cpp

```
static unique_ptr<ObjectManager> create(ObjectType type)
{
    return make_unique<ObjectManager>(type);
}
```

---

### main.cpp

```
auto createType = make_unique<ObjectManager>(ObjectType::type1);
```

Comment: `make_unique` is effectively calling `new` (as you can see in your error message) and you can't `new` an enum value. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd guess your ObjectFactory::create is supposed to create some other class depending on the value of type, not try and make an instance of type itself?

Comment: Yes, my mistake

Comment: Now it throws another error. I edited my question

Comment: ObjectManager is an abstract class because it has `virtual ... = 0` function declarations. You'll need to create concrete subclasses of it that implement all of those methods and then `make_unique` one of those instead.

Comment: Essentialy you need to `switch` between different `make_unique<...>()` calls depending on the value of the parameter.

Comment: What does the `ObjectManager` constructor look like? It should have a converting constructor taking an `ObjectType` as argument the way you've written it now. Otherwise, do the `switch`ing as HoleBlackCat suggests.

Comment: It doesn't have such constructor. Now I understood that it needs it. But I don't understand how to do this. It's my first time with pointers

Comment: @Alina It doesn't need it if you do the switching in the factory as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: Aside: `ObjectFactory` may as well be a `namespace`. C++ isn't Java

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `type1`, `type2` and `type3` maps to classes that are derived from `ObjectManager`. I call them `Manager1`, `Manager2` and `Manager3` below:

```
std::unique_ptr<ObjectManager> ObjectFactory::create(ObjectType type)
{
    switch(type) {
    case ObjectType::type1: return std::make_unique<Manager1>();
    case ObjectType::type2: return std::make_unique<Manager2>();
    case ObjectType::type3: return std::make_unique<Manager3>();
    }
    return nullptr; // or {} or throw a runtime_error
}
```

You should also add a `virtual` destructor to your base class, otherwise `delete` on a base class pointer will not call the derived class' destructor.

```
class ObjectManager {
public:
    //...
    virtual ~ObjectManager() = default;
    //...
};
```

Since you have a factory class, you should use that in your `main`:

```
auto createType = ObjectFactory::create(ObjectType::type1);
```